# Excel Formula If functionHelp

Tags: excel-formula

[Help Main Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hXjk.png)

[First Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9PHw.png)

[Main Data Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgKKB.png)

Why Hello!

I am having a hard time completing an in-depth if function.  Here is my issue:

I have a list in Column A with drop down buttons.  Out of those 60 items, I need 5 of them to have a running total IF they are selected.  Currently my function looks like this but obviously isn't working if I am asking here.  It will not keep a running total in the same cell if any combination are chosen.  IE if 1 is chosen cell value = 4.  If 2 are chosen cell value = 8

=IF(OR(COUNTIF(Testing!C12:E27,CharacterSkills!B4),COUNTIF(Testing!C12:E27,CharacterSkills!B6),COUNTIF(Testing!C12:E27,CharacterSkills!B16),COUNTIF(Testing!C12:E27,CharacterSkills!B25),COUNTIF(Testing!C12:E27,CharacterSkills!B28),COUNTIF(Testing!C12:E27,CharacterSkills!B31)),A18+4,0)

Specifics:

MainSheet: Cell C12:E27 are drop downs pulling from "Data Table" Photo (The selection is filtered by Cell E6 (Class).  Using Data Validation =OFFSET(CharacterSkills!$A$1,MATCH($E$5,CharacterSkills!$A:$A,0)-1,1,COUNTIF(CharacterSkills!$A:$A,$E$5),1)

First Data:  Cell B18 is the cell I would like to keep a running total in.  For example, everytime Arcane Magic, or Divine Magic is selected I would like it to add 4 to that cell each time

Data Table:  This is the main data table for the drop downs on the MainSheet.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: It's not very clear what your question is. What are the values present in the drop downs in Column A? What does the running total consist of? Values in column A? If so, which values (how do the drop downs indicate which values to total). A sample of data would help immensely as well.

Comment: Sadly it won't let me add images yet to my post to show.

Comment: What XP do you need? I just upvoted to put you at 6.

Comment: 10.  I just made an account.  I did manage to get one up there but that is all it will show.  Now my post doesn't make sense.

Comment: Try now, Krunch

Comment: Wow.  I have never met a help site that is this kind.

Comment: So, in cell B18 on the sheet "First Data", you want to add 4 anytime Arcane Magic or Divine Magic show up in column A on a different sheet? Just want to make sure I'm understanding right. Is this some sort of calculator for D&D?

Comment: That is correct with the goals. It will be added with what ever is populated with A18 on the sheet "First Data".  Anytime Arcane Magic or Divine Magic (others labels will be added in the future) show up in column C12:E27 on the "Help Main Sheet." And not quite D&D.  A bit more nerdy.  It's for a very in-depth low-fantasy high-immersion Larp group.

Comment: Sounds like fun! I'll post up an answer. I think it will be a bit more simple than you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell B18 on the sheet "First Data", input the formula below. This will work for the test case given. If you want this to be more dynamic (ie input all the things that necessitate a +4 in a range and just reference that) you will need a more complex formula. I am happy to help with that as well, but thought I would give you this, which fits the criteria above.

```
=(Countifs(Testing!C12:E27,"Arcane Magic") + Countifs(Testing!C12:E27,"Divine Magic"))*4
```

More complicated answer:

Let's say instead of stringing together `Countifs()` statement, you had a range `Testing!XFD1:XFD2` and in `XFD1` you have `Arcane Magic` and in `XFD2` you have `Divine Magic`. If this were the case, you could instead use:

```
{=SUM(COUNTIFS(Testing!C12:E27,Testing!XFD1:XFD2))*4}
```

Note this must be entered using `Shift + Ctrl + Enter`. The curly braces will be input when you enter the formula, you do not enter those on your own.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks! Not sure what I was thinking with my initial if or statements.

It would seem all I have to do is add additional countifs with the proper label to each skill to make it extend to all skills that user it.  It works so I am happy.  No need to make unecessary work to simplify it.

Comment: Can't edit my response.  What is the meaning of the "*" symbol prior to the 4?

Comment: It is the multiplication symbol in Excel. So, it is counting all instances of "Arcane Magic" and adding that to the count of all instances of "Divine Magic" then multiplying that total by 4. If this solution works, will you please accept the answer?

Comment: Sure thing!  And thanks again for all the help!  I am curious on the more complex way but it isn't necessary